# Flink CLI vs Flink Web Console

Tags: apache-flink

We have a requirement where to replace flink console UI and enable all the functionalities of Flink Web console using CLI utilities, for some of the functionalities like starting job, save-points etc we are using Flink CLI.

My questions are

1. Does Flink CLI has parity with Flink Web UI Console?
2. If not, is there alternate ways to do things without ui what is possible via Flink Console (like checking/monitoring back pressure of a job etc)

I am trying to find a solution where on-call engineer can completely monitor and operate on flink using command line / terminal without need to go to web ui

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory the Flink CLI plus the REST api provide a superset of the functionality available via the web UI. But some things, like identifying a busy task that's causing backpressure, can be done much more quickly with the web UI. For monitoring and troubleshooting I think you'll need to either build some tooling and/or set up a metrics dashboard (e.g., using Grafana in combination with your preferred metrics reporter).

Comment: Thanks. Looks like complete replacement of web UI with CLI isn't a viable option